# Update a record using radio button

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button, selection

I am trying to update some records using radio buttons I want only the selected record to be updated but it keeps on updating the records from beginning to end . Can anyone tell what is that I am missing

```
 <?php
  $query = mysql_connect("localhost","root","toor");
   mysql_select_db("busticket",$query);
   $result=mysql_query("Select * from ticket_reservation") or      die(mysql_error());
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' name='name[]'   value='".$row['id']."'</td><td> '".$row['id']."'</td><td>".$row['userid']."</td> <td>".$row['busid']."</td><td>".$row['numberofseats']."</td></tr>";
     }
     echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='submit[]' value='validate'> </td></tr>";
    ?>
   <?php 
    $name=$_POST['name'];

    $qry="UPDATE ticket_reservation set validate_status='Yes'";
    mysql_query($qry);     

   ?>
```

Comment: `UPDATE ... WHERE id = :id`?

Comment: You need a where clause to your update statement otherwise, as you noticed, all records will be updated. Also, the radio input field is not closed correctly

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of issues with the above code, the main one being that there was no `where` clause specified to your `update` statement - thus all records get updated when the form is submitted. The `radio` button was not closed correctly so would have caused issues with the flow of the html. The `update` clause requires a POSTed variable `name` yet there was nothing to prevent the server trying to execute the statement in a normal GET request - hence enclosing in the `IF` statement.

```
/* Create db connection */
$query = mysql_connect( "localhost", "root", "toor" );
mysql_select_db( "busticket", $query );

/* Update records */
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    /* Because the field `name` is called `name[]` - array - you need to specify the item in the array, should be the first one ie: index 0 */
    $qry="UPDATE `ticket_reservation` set `validate_status`='Yes' where `id`='".$name[0]."';";
    mysql_query( $qry );
}

/* Display records */
$result=mysql_query("Select * from `ticket_reservation`") or die( 'Error: There was a problem with the query' );

echo "<table>";
while( $row=mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td><input type='radio' name='name[]' value='".$row['id']."'></td>
        <td>".$row['id']."</td>
        <td>".$row['userid']."</td>
        <td>".$row['busid']."</td>
        <td>".$row['numberofseats']."</td>
    </tr>";
}
echo "<tr><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='validate'></td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I have replaced the code but now it shows no change at all cost...database does not change also I want to ask why you have added two semicolons in the update query?

Comment: Try echoing out the sql before it gets executed in the update area. There are two semi-colons because one is used within sql to terminate a statement and the other terminates the php line ending.

Comment: It says the following when echo $qry executes. UPDATE `ticket_reservation` set `validate_status`='Yes' where `id`='Array';

Comment: That is because you are using `name[]` as the field. Check updated answer above

Comment: I have checked mysql_select_db($dbname); It says Access denied for the user ' '@localhost Using password No. I think tnis might be a problem ....is it so?

Comment: that would appear to be an issue - check that you can connect to the db using those credentials with your mysql gui ( heidi etc )